# Widget should be refresh when its data belongs to StreamBuilder's stream in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a simple EXPENSE MANAGER app

I have divided screen in two section

Top Section for showing Two card of TotalIncome and TotalExpense
and other section is showing All Transactions

Here, I have taken Streambuilder for showing all transaction, and with the help of this stream builder **I have created Tow Global Variable totalincome and totalexpense**

and showing total income and totalexpense to top section's Card

When I add any transaction, List of transaction refresh properly as it is due to Stream Builder but total income and expense card not refreshing...

here I want the proper way to do it...(
like creating a method that fetch records from firebase and store into a List and to use this list for various needs...

here Is my code

```
Widget headerSummary(Size size) {
    return Container(
      height: size.height * 0.15,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(30), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30)),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Expanded(

            child: SummaryCard(
              color: Colors.green,
              amount: totalincome.toString(),
              icondata: Icons.arrow_upward,
              title: 'Income',
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SummaryCard(
              color: Colors.red,
              amount: totalexpense.toString(),
              icondata: Icons.arrow_downward,
              title: 'Expense',
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

transaction

```
Widget showTransactions(Size size) {
    return Container(
      height: size.height * .65,
      // color: Colors.red,
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(widget.loggeduser.userid)
              .collection('expenses').orderBy("date",descending: true)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                QuerySnapshot querysnapshot =
                snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot;
                if (querysnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                  List<Map<String, dynamic>> transactionlist = [];
                  for (int x = 0; x < querysnapshot.docs.length; x++) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> expensemap = querysnapshot.docs[x]
                        .data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    transactionlist.add(expensemap);
                  }

                   var x=transactionlist.where((element) => element['isexpense']==true).toList();
                  totalexpense=x.fold(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue+element['amount']);


                  var y=transactionlist.where((element) => element['isexpense']==false).toList();
                  totalincome=y.fold(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue+element['amount']);
//I have edited this lines...





                  return ListView.builder(
                    //reverse: true,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                      itemCount: transactionlist.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                       final trans=TransactionModel.fromjson(transactionlist[index]);
                       print(trans.toString());
                        return TransactionCard(
                          amount: trans.amount.toStringAsFixed(2),
                          datetime: trans.date.toString(),
                          paymentby: trans.paymentmode,
                          category: trans.category.title,
                          categoryicon: trans.category.iconurl,
                          isexpense: trans.isexpense,
                        );
                      });//listview end
                } else {
                  return Container(
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text('No Transaction Found...')));
                }
              } else {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('error found');
                } else {
                  return Text('empty..');
                }
              }
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          }),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StreamBuilder will refresh its child UI, not the upper widget.

You can use `ValueNotifier` with `ValueListenableBuilder`. This snippet will help you to clear the concept.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

int? myGlobalValue1;

ValueNotifier<int?> globalValueNotifier = ValueNotifier(null);

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("myGlobalValue1 $myGlobalValue1"),
            ValueListenableBuilder<int?>(
                valueListenable: globalValueNotifier,
                builder: (context, value, child) {
                  return Text("globalValueNotifier $value");
                }),
            StreamBuilder<int>(
              stream: Stream<int>.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (x) => x)
                  .take(15),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                myGlobalValue1 = snapshot.data;

                WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  globalValueNotifier.value = snapshot.data; // to skip initOn frame build
                });
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      snapshot.data != null ? snapshot.data.toString() : "0",
                    ),
                    Text("myGlobalValue1 inside streamB $myGlobalValue1"),
                  ],
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: its done but for a single variable such long code...what if I have many variables...?

Comment: State-management is the solution, try riverpod/bloc

Comment: I know only provider...will it work

Comment: yap, It will work too, btw you may like riverpod ,while you are a provider user

Comment: Thanks....by the way..what topic should I learn for such code ```WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_)```

Comment: This is was needed to fix rebuild issue while changing data.  [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html), I think you wont be needed this with provider

Comment: Okay good....here I needed two variable for income and expense.. I tried with creating map...but failing to manage value notifier...{'income':0.0,'expense':0.0}

Comment: don't need code..but is it possible ```ValueNotifier<int?> globalValueNotifier = ValueNotifier(null);``` instead I take ```ValueNotifier<Map<String,double>> globalvalueNotifier=ValueNotifier(null)```

Comment: how you are changing the value

Comment: in future, you may use provider ,

Comment: Provider is the right choice....but WidgetBinding will help for some single value...Thanks to stack overflow it has your kind of experts...otherwise it would be tough to get solved...

Comment: Glad to help, I am also learning flutter ✌

Answer (score 1):

1. You could move StreamBuilder further up in the widget tree, so that showTransactions and headerSummary get built within the Stream Builder.
2. If you want to keep the layout as it is, then you could look into ValueNotifier to update Income and Expense variables when stream builder has an update.